# Source code examples in C# or C++ that calculates heart rate variability windows 10

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth

I am trying to get the heart rate variability from Polar device.

And I am running [Windows Universal sample BLE](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothLE/cs) to connect to the device and get the HRV. It looks like [this](https://ibb.co/m2tqrp). (the device is actually Polar h10).

As you can see I can get the Heart rates but it's not giving me HRV.
First of all, I was hoping that when I select the HeartRate characteristic I will have an option for Heart rate variability as well. But not really! (That would have been really nice and easy :)

```
"180d"    /* Heart Rate */    

"2a37": "Heart Rate Measurement",
"2a38": "Body Sensor Location"
// This is where it should show Heart Rate Variability //
```

And I have searched enough to find some HRV example in C# but there are not any.

Even on Github there are mostly android examples in java and others are in Python and Matlab.

And surprisingly the ones that are in java does not show any calculations on how to get HRV which is weird.

**Can someone help me find the examples in C#, C++ or just help me find any code examples that shows the calculation for HRV?**

Comment: Does your health  device could  provide HRV data?

Comment: Yes it does provide Variability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have found an answer.  I have followed this answer by GrooverFromHolland.

This was his answer:

If you can read the heartbeat in notifications than there is also the rr-interval. The rr-interval is represented 2 bytes( uint16). You need the rr-interval to calculate heart rate variability in your app.

To get the rr-interval you have to read the flags from the first byte you receive. You read the flags as binary from right to left.

bit 0 = 0: Heart Rate Value Format is set to UINT8. Units:BPM (1 byte).
bit 0 = 1: Heart Rate Value Format is set to UINT16. Units:BPM (2 bytes).

bit 1 and 2: Sensor Contact Status bits. These are not relevant for this.

bit 3 = 0: Energy Expended field is not present.
bit 3 = 1: Energy Expended field is present. Format = uint16. Units: kilo Joules.

bit 4 = 0: RR-Interval values are not present.
bit 4 = 1: One or more RR-Interval values are present. Format = uint16. unit 1/1024 sec.

bit 5, 6 and 7: reserved for future use.

If your first byte for example = 16 = 0x10 = 0b00010000 then byte 2 = is heart rate.

Byte 3 and 4 are the rr-interval.
Byte 5 and 6 (if present) rr-interval.

To calculate heart rate variability you have to sample the rr-interval values over a period of time and take the Standard Deviation of those intervals. To calculate the Standard Deviation:

```
1. Work out the Mean (the simple average of the numbers)
2. Then for each number: subtract the Mean and square the result
3. Then work out the mean of those squared differences.
4. Take the square root of that and we are done!
```

How to do that in code, I leave that up to You or you can google it.

Note:

Byte-pairs in SIG specifications are Least Significant Byte First, so for uint16 representation in Windows swap the bytes of a byte-pair first!
rr-interval is not miliseconds but 1/1024 seconds. This is to prevent loosing the decimal numbers in an unsigned division.

(Someone please undo -1 to the question)